# Will doing an IIS reset cause any problem for SharePoint sites?

Tags: sharepoint-server, iis

I want to know if doing an IIS reset it will cause any problem for SharePoint 2013 server site. Can anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 6):

It simply recycles all the application pools in IIS on the server you run the command on. While they are recycling, all the web appliction caches are emptied, and SharePoint will be unable to handle request to said server until the recycling is done.

If you only have one webfront server, SharePoint will be unavailable during the recycle. Your sites will be slower to load due to the cached css and such is removed but only for a little while.

Answer (score 6):

As it tries to shutdown all IIS components first,

- HTTP.SYS will loose existing client-connections after running IISRESET.
- All incoming requests will need to establish new connections(port 80 by default) again.
- Web browsers can’t connect the IIS server during restarting IIS (downtime).

. While its restarting services, requests from browsers are being missed. (downtime)

- A worker process can’t keep any data – cached objects & binaries
- In-Process session state, compiled binaries for ASP/ASP.NET in a process memory, Application cache.
- Any data, stored in a worker process(W3WP.EXE) will be lost.
- In-Proc session state, compiled binaries of ASP/ASP.NET in a process memory, application cache

Source: https://fullsocrates.wordpress.com/2012/07/25/iisreset-vs-recycling-application-pools/

Comment: If you copy and paste someones material, please add the source. https://fullsocrates.wordpress.com/2012/07/25/iisreset-vs-recycling-application-pools/

Comment: @Christoffer : sure, will keep in mind from next time :)

Answer (score 4):

As regarding to SharePoint only , IIS Reset will not cause any major problem but Its not good to do frequently as its not good for performance. it has **some side effects** such as,

1. Taking much time on initial site load,
2. Performance issue while accessing content from SharePoint (until next caching).
3. Sometime its stops your application pool so site becomes unavailable (HTTP 503).
4. It affects all other applications/asp.net sites hosted on iis.

**Some important notes:**

1. There are lots of situation where Developer/Admin need to do IIS reset like after changing any farm level settings, while registering or deploying some farm solutions.
2. First thing you have to try is recycle the application pool of the application. You should try iis reset if recycling app pool doesn't help.
3. **Doing the IIS Reset in non-working hours is a good practice.**